# When I dump my database , 75% was already Okay.But It returns failed :document is corrupted

Tags: document, corrupt, mongodump

When I dump my database, 75% was already Okay. But It returns failed: the document is corrupted. What should I do

Comment: What are you going to achieve? What is the error message?

Comment: I am going to use a command mongodump. But something wrong.ERRO:DOCUMENT IS CORRUTED.